# making list of white space separated numbers from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I want to read some numbers from a file which are, which I am unable to read in two lists for further calculation like Mean and STDEV.
   0.0000000    0.0000005
   0.0100000    0.1675796
   0.0200000    0.2042502
   0.0300000    0.2064999
   0.0400000    0.2237432
   0.0500000    0.2245723
   0.0600000    0.2365732
   0.0700000    0.2433299
   0.0800000    0.2556339
   0.0900000    0.2569953
   0.1000000    0.2658122
   0.1100000    0.2718526
   0.1200000    0.2741648

```
import os 

directory= "/media/quinn/Joker/post_analysis/KBH00"

for x in range (252, 256):
    os.chdir(directory + str(x) +'/')
    print(os.getcwd())
    with open ('rmsd.xvg', 'r') as rmsd:
      line_19_to_end = rmsd.readlines()[18:]
      print("Values of RMSD are:")
      for line in line_19_to_end:
        print("%s" %(line))
```

Comment: us can use `line_19_to_end  = list(map(float, line_19_to_end.split()))`

Comment: The problem is my data is in two columns and I can't use split in that condition.

Comment: Why can't you use split?  Can you show the structure of the data in your file, if it isn't simply two space-separated floats per line?

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating add all values at the 0th position to a new list `col1` and 1st position to another list `col2`, after conferring each values to float.

```
import os 

directory= "/media/quinn/Joker/post_analysis/KBH00"

for x in range (252, 256):
    os.chdir(directory + str(x) +'/')
    print(os.getcwd())
    col1,col2=[],[]
    with open ('rmsd.xvg', 'r') as rmsd:
      line_19_to_end = rmsd.readlines()[18:]
      print("Values of RMSD are:")
      for line in line_19_to_end:
        print("%s" %(line))
        line = list(map(float, line.split()))
        col1.append(line[0])
        col2.append(line[1])
print(col1,'\n',col2)
```